# Godot: How can I rotate player in direction of travel?

Tags: godot

Hi there I am trying to rotate my player into the direction that it is travelling in godot. Here is the code:

```
if Input.is_action_pressed("move_forward"):
    rotate_object_local(Vector3.UP, 1)
    transform.basis = Basis()
if Input.is_action_pressed("move_backward"):
    rotate_object_local(Vector3.UP, -1)
    transform.basis = Basis()
if Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
    rotate_object_local(Vector3.LEFT, 1)
    transform.basis = Basis()
if Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
    rotate_object_local(Vector3.LEFT, -1)
    transform.basis = Basis()
```

I've gone through countless forums and tutorials trying to figure out why it isn't working. Any help is much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

A `Transform` in Godot has two parts:

- `basis`: a `Basis` that holds the direction and scale of each axis. Essentially a 3 by 3 matrix.
- `origin`: a `Vector3` that holds the translation.

---

Now, look at your code. You are setting the `basis` to the default:

```
transform.basis = Basis()
```

*Here `Basis()` is a call to the default constructor of `Basis`, which gives you an identity `Basis`.*

And, as you would expect, that will reset any rotation. It is undoing whatever `rotate_object_local` did. Thus the posted code has no effect.

If don't set the `basis`, you should be able to observe rotation.

---

Presumably you wanted to reset the rotation *before* applying the new one. For example:

```
    transform.basis = Basis()
    rotate_object_local(Vector3.UP, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks so much that makes a lot more sense I will try it now